# ManyToOne gives null in Spring Boot Test

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-test, many-to-one

I have an entity **UserMicroService** like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_service")
public class UserMicroService extends BaseAccountEntity<Long> {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String userId;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private User user;

    // getters and setters
}
```

I need both `userId` and `user` fields. To achieve this, I have to mark my user field annotation with additional parameters:

`optional = false`
`insertable = false, updatable = false`

And it works just perfectly in the app. But when I run Spring Boot Test, the user field is null.

```
@Transactional
@SpringBootTest
@ActiveProfiles("test")
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class TelegramNotificationServiceIT {

    @Autowired
    private TelegramNotificationService telegramNotificationService;

    @MockBean
    private TelegramNotificationQueueService telegramNotificationQueueService;


    @Test
    public void processServiceNotifications_noUsers() {
        telegramNotificationService.processServiceNotifications();
        verify(telegramNotificationQueueService, times(0)).add(any());
    }
}
```

The repository is Spring Data Jpa with method:

`List<UserMicroService> findByServiceAndBalanceAndCurrentEndDateBetween(ServiceName service, BigDecimal balance, LocalDateTime from, LocalDateTime to);`

Comment: Provided code is not enough to conclude where the problem could be (missing `User` and `TelegramNotificationService` classes, `processServiceNotifications()` method code), but as it works in production, I would guess that maybe [OSIV](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-open-session-in-view-anti-pattern/) is enabled and masks the problem there.

Comment: @MartinBG TelegramNotificationService simply calls another service. Another service calls repository with the method I described above.